# Kafka RecordMetadata use?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

What is advantage of using RecordMetadata to get topic, partition etc rather than taking it from consumer record itself if those are available in it?

I was able to get topic, partition etc using corresponding methods from consumer record itself like:

```
consumerRecord.topic()
```

Then what is the advantage of RecordMetadata to obtain these?

Are there any performance improvements for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answer says, `RecordMetadata` is created on the producer side.

If you are talking about `ConsumerRecordMetadata` (a Spring concept), it is not intended for use when you consume the raw `ConsumerRecord`; it is used when you have a POJO listener (for just the `value()`) but you still want to obtain metadata.

Answer (score 2):

The [RecordMetadata](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/RecordMetadata.html) object is returned on `KafkaProducer.send` while producing the data into topic

> The send() method is asynchronous. When called it adds the record to a buffer of pending record sends and immediately returns. This allows the producer to batch together individual records for efficiency.

> The producer consists of a pool of buffer space that holds records that haven't yet been transmitted to the server as well as a background I/O thread that is responsible for turning these records into requests and transmitting them to the cluster. Failure to close the producer after use will leak these resources.

Since the `send` method returns `Future<RecordMetadata>` and result of every record is executed my asynchronous thread, you can add [call back](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html#send-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord-org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Callback-) to print the `offset`, `partition` and record information or the exception on failure

```
  ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]> record = new 
  ProducerRecord<byte[],byte[]>("the-topic", key, value);
  producer.send(myRecord,
           new Callback() {
               public void onCompletion(RecordMetadata metadata, Exception e) {
                   if(e != null) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                   } else {
                      System.out.println("The offset of the record we just sent is: " + metadata.offset());
                   }
               }
           });
```

**Note :** While producing the record into Kafka topic, due to the asynchronous mechanism the thread invoking `send` method will be different than the threads executing the `Future<RecordMetadata>` result.

Comment: Can you please explain it's advantages from the kafka consumer's point of view as well?

Comment: consuming records is different process, i would recommend you to go through this documentation https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html